# Make a control transparent

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there any way to make a control transparent like button, edit, panel or etc...? I mean something like opacity or alpha blend that we have in form property.

Comment: You can get transparent buttons or panels in a variety of open source or free ones.  You do not typically "make" your existing controls transparent, as this is usually a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some components have the *transparent* property. In others you can choose 'none' as the *color* property. It differs from component to component, but not all components can be made transparent by changing a property.

You should try googling Delphi transparent components, there are downloadable components and tricks you can do to make existing components transparent.

Comment: I googled it over 6 months and found no useful solution. It can happen because i have 3 reasons: 1- When a form can have it, other controls can have it too! 2- I've seen that in some applications 3- Anything is possible in programming, especially when you are using DELPHI! Thanks at all.

Comment: Oh, what I meant to say was I didn't think it was possible to make a component transparent by changing a property.  
I have actually tried making a panel transparent (not my code though), this is what I meant by tricks to make existing components transparent. 
I've never actually found a code that works on every component, but most of them manipulate/override/deal with the Paint procedure/method.

Comment: Constructive answers doesn't start with "I think" or "I don't think"

Comment: I was inexperienced and I do not like feigning certainty when I am not certain. I will edit this when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Win32 windows styles, especially WS_TRANSPARENT (or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT).

Comment: I've seen that work on Windows. I'm not sure if it does on components though... will have to research it sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Applying transparency on a child control can be done very easily using old-fashioned regions and the `SetWindowRgn()` function.

Applying alpha blending on a child control, on the other hand, is very difficult to do prior to Windows 8.  It involves painting the parent window to a bitmap first, then alpha blending an image of the child control on top of the bitmap, then rendering the bitmap onscreen.

In Windows 8, the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style (which is what Tform's `TransparentColor` and `AlphaBlendValue` properties use internally) has finally been implemented for child controls.